# ListView with setItem onClickListner method

Tags: android

```
         public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.word_list);

          ArrayList<Words> numbers = new ArrayList<Words>();
          numbers.add(new Words("one","lutti",R.drawable.number_one));
          numbers.add(new Words("two","otiiko",R.drawable.number_two));
          numbers.add(new Words("three","tolookosu",R.drawable.number_three));
          numbers.add(new Words("four","oyyisa",R.drawable.number_four));
          numbers.add(new Words("five","massokka",R.drawable.number_five));
          numbers.add(new Words("six","temmokka",R.drawable.number_six));
          numbers.add(new Words("seven","kenekaku",R.drawable.number_seven));
          numbers.add(new Words("eight","kawinta",R.drawable.number_eight));
          numbers.add(new Words("nine","wo’e",R.drawable.number_nine));
          numbers.add(new Words("ten","na’aacha",R.drawable.number_ten));
       WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, numbers, R.color.category_numbers);
      ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast display = Toast.makeText(NumbersActivity.this,"it is some text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            display.show();

        }
    });
}
```

}

**code is without errors but I am not able to get toast message , click is not working within the app**, should we modify or add anything additionally to the existing code

the below is the code related to WordAdapter class

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Words> {

/** Resource ID for the background color for this list of words */
private int mColorResourceId;



/**
 * Create a new {@link WordAdapter} object.
 *
 * @param context is the current context (i.e. Activity) that the adapter is being created in.
 * @param words is the list of {@link Words}s to be displayed.
 * @param colorResourceId is the resource ID for the background color for this list of words
 */
public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Words> words, int colorResourceId) {
    super(context, 0, words);
    mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
}





@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }


    Words wordsTranslation = getItem(position);

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
    TextView englishTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.englishWord);

    englishTextView.setText(wordsTranslation.getDefaultEnglish());

    TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwokWord);

    miwokTextView.setText(wordsTranslation.getTranslatedMiwok());


    // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID image.
    ImageView sideImage = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    // Check if an image is provided for this word or not
    if (wordsTranslation.hasImage()) {
        // If an image is available, display the provided image based on the resource ID
         sideImage.setImageResource(wordsTranslation.getImage());
        // Make sure the view is visible
        sideImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
           sideImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
    textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);

    return listItemView;
}
```

}

Comment: post your android layout

Comment: If you tried the every answers that the people gave to you and does not work.. try clean your project, uninstall the app in your device and compile again(and post your android layout btw)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create parent layout as a Linear or relative layout which includes your englishTextView, miwokTextView and your sideImage.

like

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/englishTextView />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/miwokTextView />
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/sideImage/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in your WordAdapter class find LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast display = Toast.makeText(context,"it is some text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    display.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems nothing wrong.

I need more code to confirm. like WordAdapter etc.

Another thing, you can use code

```
Log.d("ss","position " + position + " id " + id);
```

in your function onItemClick().

If not worked in onItemClick(), something must be wrong in your WordAdapter.

-----------------------UPDATE------------------------------------

Hi mvs,

using your code,it seems could show your Toast.

Code in WordAdapter:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }


    Words wordsTranslation = getItem(position);
    TextView englishTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.textItem);

    englishTextView.setText(position + "");
    /**
     TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwokWord);

     miwokTextView.setText(wordsTranslation.getTranslatedMiwok());


     // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID image.
     ImageView sideImage = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

     // Check if an image is provided for this word or not
     if (wordsTranslation.hasImage()) {
     // If an image is available, display the provided image based on the resource ID
     sideImage.setImageResource(wordsTranslation.getImage());
     // Make sure the view is visible
     sideImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     } else {
     sideImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }

     View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
     int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
     textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);
     **/

    return listItemView;
}
```

Two possibilities:

1. in code WordAdapter comment, detail check unused code(I have commented)

**2.Some Phone, Like Samsung, you should turn on 'Toast' in System Settings. So, Please use code   `Log.d("ss","position " + position + " id " + id);` to see whether onItemClick() is executed in NumberActivity. if  executed, it is your phone's problem.**

[image]

Comment: I have added wordAdapter class as you mentioned that you want it to debug more , i am not able to click the listview -- there is no response from listview ,,. What is the use of adding log.d log message i could not see anything related to it

Answer (score 0):

Put onClickListener in Adapter class.

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Words> {

private int mColorResourceId;
Context context;


public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Words> words, int colorResourceId) {
super(context, 0, words);
this.context=context;
mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
View listItemView = convertView;
if(listItemView == null) {
    listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
}


Words wordsTranslation = getItem(position);

// Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
TextView englishTextView = (TextView)    listItemView.findViewById(R.id.englishWord);

englishTextView.setText(wordsTranslation.getDefaultEnglish());

TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwokWord);

miwokTextView.setText(wordsTranslation.getTranslatedMiwok());


// Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID image.
ImageView sideImage = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

// Check if an image is provided for this word or not
if (wordsTranslation.hasImage()) {
    // If an image is available, display the provided image based on the resource ID
     sideImage.setImageResource(wordsTranslation.getImage());
    // Make sure the view is visible
    sideImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
       sideImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);
 listItemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
  Toast display = Toast.makeText(context,"it is some text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        display.show();
        }
    });

return listItemView;
}
}
```

Comment: it is completely false condiotion which you have stated nothing working in that manner

Comment: What problem are you getting.

Comment: my intention is to get a toast message when i clicked on the listview

Comment: nothing has changed after adding the following given by you in the wordAdapter class , it is as it is before one

Comment: I use this code for displaying messages in the list view and OnClickListener workd on them.I don't understand why it's not working for you.